# DB table many-to-many connection to children and grandchildren directly

Tags: database, many-to-many, schema, relational-database

I'm designing a database with a connection I haven't encountered before and wondering the best approach.

Let's say I have an Invoice, and that invoice can be assigned to an Organization, or an Individual, and in some cases that individual can be part of an Organization.

The way I have this thought-out so far is as follows:

```
Organizations    Invoices           Individuals
-pk              -pk                -pk
-name            -organization_id   -org_member_id
-address_id      -individual_id     -name
-...             -...               -...
```

So if an invoice is assigned to an individual, the individual_id is used. If that individual is associated with an organization then a `through` association would pick that up... (but i imagine organization_id would remain nil?) However if only an organization is assigned to the invoice then individual_id would of course be nil.

Not sure what the best way to go about this is. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways in which you can approach this.
One approach : as you mentioned, if the Invoice is individual based, then only `individual_id` is filled while keeping the organization_id as null. If that individual is part of an organization, then you can fill that organization's ID in to `organization_id` - so this column can be NULLABLE in your schema. If invoice is assigned to an organization only, then fill that id and keep `individual_id` as NULL.

*Another approach* : Introduce a column named `assignee_type` [char(1)] and use either O or I to determine the type of assignment, and just fill the `assignee_id` column with either Individual or Organization ID only. When you query the data, you need to refer the assignee_type column and then based on that join with either Organization table or Individual table - this can add overhead.
Both approaches have their own pros and cons, it depends on how your retrievals are going to be from this Invoice table, that will influence which approach you could take.

Comment: Excellent. Makes sense. I figured there would be another approach other than the one I originally had in mind. I can imagine other parts of this DB that would be better suited for the latter. I think for the invoice section, the former might be simplest. Thank you!